# Ruby API (RabbitMQ create user)

Tags: ruby, curl, rabbitmq

Started working on Ruby a week back. Writing an API to connect to RabbitMQ messaging queue. The command line for adding a new user works.

$ curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XPUT -d'{"password":"pwd","tags":"administrator"}' http://localhost:15672/api/users/username

I need to make this Http Put request from Ruby. The following is my code:
def test_add_user

```
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:15672/api/users/karthik/')
uri.to_s
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.path)
request.basic_auth 'guest', 'guest'
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
request['Accept'] = 'application/json'
request.set_form_data({'password' => 'secret', 'tags' => 'management'})
http.start do |http|
res = http.request(request)
puts res
end
```

end

This is the result I get

```
o.test_add_user
#<Net::HTTPUnsupportedMediaType:0x007fd7fb6fe1d8>
=> nil
```

Does Media type exception relate with Content-Type? 
**Only application/json is allowed**

Should I use anything like to_json? If yes, where should it be used? Thanks in advance.

Regards
Karthik

Comment: You are wrong about `=> nil` being `res`. `puts` returns `nil`, but `res` equals `#<Net::HTTPUnsupportedMediaType:0x007fd7fb6fe1d8>` meaning the error you are getting has to do with an unsupported media type.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was expecting a number say 403 or 415.

Comment: I suspect set_form_data is not passing JSON. Instead of `request.set_form_data()` use `request.body = '{"password":"pwd","tags":"administrator"}'` (a string with JSON inside) and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Hector and ptd. Fixed it. Attached the working code for future reference.

```
def test_add_user
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:15672/api/users/Test1/')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.path)
request.basic_auth 'guest', 'guest'
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
request['Accept'] = 'application/json'
request.body = {'password' => 'secret', 'tags' => 'management'}.to_json
http.start do |http|
  res = http.request(request)
  puts res
  end
end
```

Adds a new user to the RabbitMQ queue